# SwiftUI: JSON index always out of range

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I wonder why my index is always out of range. I'm trying to parse JSON locally. Here are my codes. Thank you.

Article Model

```
struct Article: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let snapshot: String
}
```

Parse JSON

```
class TopicsViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var articles = [Article]()

func getArticles(selectedTopic: Int) {
    switch selectedTopic {
    case 0:
        self.articles = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Article].self, from: JSON.data(using: .utf8)!)
    default:
        articles = []
    }
}
}
```

I load the data onAppear

```
.onAppear{
            self.topicsVM.getArticles(selectedTopic: self.whichTopic)
    }
```

Here were the error begin

```
Text(topicsVM.articles[0].title).foregroundColor(Color.black)
```

[First image, showing Model and Parse function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2236L.png)

[Second image, showing Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3zkv.png)

Comment: Surely if `self.whichTopic` is not `0` you will get this problem?

Comment: No, in this case assume that whichTopic (self.whichTopic) is always 0. When I Text(String(self.articles.count)), it always return the correct size. But for unknown reason, I can not access the index. Like, if I want access the zeroth item, it always return index out of arrange...

Comment: What must be happening then is that `getArticles` is getting called before the data is shown in the list. Prevent this by having some `@State` property, called `isLoaded` for example, to keep track of this. Let me know if you want a full answer.

Comment: Here is my complete code. Do you have any idea?
Thank you.

https://pastebin.com/mM1gcbvK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fix your problem you can do this in TopicsView:

```
init(whichTopic: Int) {
    self.whichTopic = whichTopic
    self.topicsVM.getArticles(selectedTopic: self.whichTopic)
}
```

This will ensure that your articles array has the data you expect before the view is constructed.
You should nevertheless do this anyway in your List:

```
                if topicsVM.articles.count > 0 {
                    Text(topicsVM.articles[0].title).foregroundColor(Color.black)
                }
```

The reason why the index is out of range, appears to be because the "topicsVM.articles" array is populated after the view is constructed. And of course an empty array does not have a [0] element.